# Audio Meter in Voice recoder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am working on Audio Voice recorder application and In that i want digital meter that show voice frequency..Means if Voice speak loudly the meter increase and if slow than meter show decrease..
 I have no idea how can i create this meter so please any one have please give me some reference.

Comment: Are you looking to show the frequency (pitch)? Just to clarify because you say in the question that you want the meter to increase if you speak loudly?

Comment: ITYM *amplitude* or *loudness* rather than *frequency* ?

Comment: @drmatt yes i want show frequency..

Answer (score 4):

Apple's [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) example code includes a LevelView class which seems to be exactly what you are looking for

Hope it help